# cURL not posting to severals urls from an database

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I'm having this problem where whenever I try to fetch the urls (from a MySQL db) and then use cURL to POST an request to the urls it will only post one of the urls. I have in total 11 urls inside my database if that changes something.

Here is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM urls");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    $url = $row['url']; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); // set url to post to 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // allow redirects 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0); // times out after Ns 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // set POST method 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=test"); // add POST fields 
    $result = curl_exec($ch); // run the whole process 
    curl_close($ch); 

    echo $result; 
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for clarification, you're trying to send in "user=test" via POST into each URL you're pulling from the DB?

Comment: @JCSickmeyer - Yes, that's correct.

Comment: for efficiency, you don't have to close/reopen curl on each iteration. you can simply have the CURLOPT_URL and curl_exec() call inside the loop. curl handles CAN be reused.

Comment: @MarcB It still doesn't do the trick. Thanks for letting me known that cURL can be reused though.

Comment: These URLs you're posting to...assuming they are meant to accept this POST parameter, are any of them secure? Or do they have secure access only 'HTTPS' requiring username and password? If so, there are some other cURL options you might need.

The only other thing I can think of it setting the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` to a higher time limit.

Comment: you should also have some error handling: `if ($result === false) { echo curl_error($ch); }`. never assume that things will work. ALWAYS check for error conditions, especially when dealing with non-local resources.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to echo $row['url'] and see what you are getting in loop?

Comment: Yes, I have and it does echo out all of them URLs inside the table.

Comment: it might your php execution time is not enough to process all requests, you can increase time limit or add this in ur script set_time_limit(0);